# How to stop JsonResult from sending model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a model class below:

```
class Person
{
   string FirstName {get;set}
   string ABNNumber {get;set} 
}
```

This object gets sent to UI via JsonResult. The problem is I don't want to sent ABNNumber to UI due to security risk.

Is there anyway (any attribute) which I can use to achive above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute [ScriptIgnore]. It will help:

```
class Person
{
    string FirstName {get;set}
    [ScriptIgnore]
    string ABNNumber {get;set} 
}
```